# Remove lines from a file

Tags: text-processing, logs

In my output file I have the below lines included multiple times along with the required output.

```
WARN: The method class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory#release() was invoked.
WARN: Please see http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#release for an explanation.
```

Here is how my output looks like.

```
####################################################################
Raw Error: count of the error records with latest trans session in "audit_preatlas_wb4370_raw_error_05012016073248" table
====================================================================
count   trans_session

WARN: The method class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory#release() was invoked.
WARN: Please see http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#release for an explanation.
********************************************************************
Raw Audit: Total records available in "audit_preatlas_wb4370_raw_audit_05012016073248" table
====================================================================
count   trans_session

Raw Audit: Distinct records of "audit_preatlas_wb4370_raw_audit_05012016073248" table
====================================================================
count   trans_session

WARN: The method class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory#release() was invoked.
WARN: Please see http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#release for an explanation.
Raw Audit : count of duns with error "gbwr_raw_audit_mandatory_field" code in "audit_preatlas_wb4370_raw_audit_05012016073248" table
====================================================================
count   trans_session   error_code

WARN: The method class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory#release() was invoked.
WARN: Please see http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#release for an explanation.
Raw Audit : count of duns with error "gbwr_raw_audit_numeric_field" code in "audit_preatlas_wb4370_raw_audit_05012016073248" table
====================================================================
count   trans_session   error_code

WARN: The method class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory#release() was invoked.
WARN: Please see http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#release for an explanation.
```

How can I remove the WARN lines alone?

Comment: `grep -v WARN:` filename

Comment: Do you want to view the file without those lines (`grep -v "^WARN"`), or update the file so those lines no longer exist (`sed .....`)?

Comment: `sed -i -e '/^WARN/d' filename` maybe ?? I mean if you want them gone from the file not just preventing them from displaying, which is what `grep` is used for. Of course you can redirect th `grep` output to a file as a second alternative.

Comment: I have a command that is generating the output. How to use grep in that case?

command > output.txt

Comment: `command | grep -v "^WARN" > output.txt`

Comment: Note that most of the commands that edit a file "in-place" (like `sed -i`) don't actually edit in place, so the resulting file is actually a completely new file (with a different inode).  In most cases, this doesn't matter at all.  In some cases (e.g. when the file is a log file still open for write, or if there are hard-links to the file that need to be preserved), it does matter.  and when it matters, it matters a lot.  `ed` is one of the few programs that can be scripted to edit a file actually in-place, retaining the same inode etc.   e.g. `printf '%s\n' 'g/^WARN: /d'  w | ed -s alex.log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are a few ways. To summarize the comments above   you can do one of the following:

awk:

```
awk '!/^WARN/' filename
```

sed:

```
sed '/^WARN/d' filename
```

grep:

```
grep -v '^WARN' filename
```